# how do I sort an array based on two properties in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to sort an array in javascript:

```
 array.sort(function(a,b){
             var score_a = $.fuzzyMatch(a['name'], user).score,
                 score_b = $.fuzzyMatch(b['name'], user).score;

            return score_a < score_b ? -1 : score_a === score_b ? 0 : 1;
       });
```

The sorting is taking the 'name' property of each row in the array and running it through my fuzzymatch function and returning a score so that most relevant matches are returned at the top of the array.

However I wish to include another property in the sort which in this case will be `a['folcode']` or `b['folcode']`

So to sumarise, how can I modify my code to always put rows that contain `['folcode'] == 4` at the top, sorted by best `['name']` match, then return `['folcode'] == 3` rows, also sorted by best name match... etc...

Comment: Please could someone explain the downvote? I am not intentionally doing anything wrong and an explanation would help me learn how to prevent such things in the future.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort by `folcode` primarily, and by `name` *within* each `folcode`, you would have to yield a comparison for `folcode` just as the one you're currently doing for `name`, but return the value of the name comparison *only in the equals condition*.

```
function(a,b) {

    var code_a = a.folcode;
    var code_b = b.folcode;

    var score_a = $.fuzzyMatch(a.name, user).score;
    var score_b = $.fuzzyMatch(b.name, user).score;

    if(code_a === code_b)
        return score_a < score_b ? -1 : score_a === score_b ? 0 : 1;

    return code_a < code_b ? -1 : 1;

}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect thank you! I also feel a bit dumb now as the solution was so simple.  Regardless,  Huge thanks. :) I will mark as answered as soon as I am able.